# RedbeanPHP, sql

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно найти и вывести данные из бд, чтобы сообщения выводились построчно и последовательно, только мне и только от меня, приватно от общего чата?

Есть вот такой код, но он сообщения выводит разделено, в верхней части мне, а в нижней, от меня:

```
        $id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;

        $mess_to = R::findAll('messages', 'WHERE to_id = ?', [$id]);
        foreach($mess_1 as $found_1) {
        echo "<b><font color='blue'>".$found_1['login']."</b>:&nbsp;</font>".$found_1['time']."<br>".$found_1['messages']."<br><br>";
        }

        $mess_from = R::findAll('messages', 'WHERE from_id = ?', [$id]);
        foreach($mess_2 as $found_2) {
        echo "<b><font color='blue'>".$found_2['login']."</b>:&nbsp;</font>".$found_2['time']."<br>".$found_2['messages']."<br><br>";
        }
```

Каким образом сделать последовательный вывод сообщений? Необходимо сделать приватный чат, а не общий.

Comment: а вас не смущает, что плейсхолдеров для параметров у вас два, а передаете вы только одно значение?

Comment: да смущает, но как правильно реализовать последовательный вывод сообщений, мне и от меня?

Comment: отсортируйте по времени отправки. напишите общий цикл вывода сообщений, внутри него проверяйте от кого сообщение, от вас или вам. Если у вас есть какие то общие/групповые чаты, то скорее всего еще есть и какой-нибудь `chat_id`, отфильтруйте сообщения по нему.

Comment: в противном случе у вас будет условие вида `(from = ? and to = ?) or (from = ? and to = ?)` где будут указаны id вас и собеседника